# jQuery autocomplete on select call a server side script

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have an application that allows users to select an activity (such as watching movies or aikido) from a jQuery autocomplete box.  That part is working.  What I want, however, is for some boxes that allow a user to select their expertise to either be disabled if expertise isn't relevant (such as watching movies) or enabled if expertise is relevant.  To do this, I'm trying to call a $.getJSON from within the autocomplete select event.  The $.getJSON calls a server-side php script that asks a mysql database if the activity just selected requires expertise.  It doesn't seem to be calling the $.getJSON, however.

Here is my HTML:

```
<label for="activity">Select Activity:</label>
<input id="activity">
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$( "#activity" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: "php/getActivities.php",
    select: function(event, ui) {

        // Call the server side script to determine whether or not this activity 
        // requires expertise or not
        queryString = 'activity=' + encodeURIComponent(ui.item.value);
        alert (queryString);

        $.getJSON('php/checkActivityExpertise.php',queryString,function(data2)  {

            alert('in .getJSON');

            if (data2.needExpertise)  {
                activateBoxes();
            }
            else {
                deactivateBoxes();
            }

        });  // end of $.getJSON call
    } // end of select: function
}); // end of activity.autocomplete
```

And here's the PHP function:

```
<?php // checkActivityExpertise.php

// Connect to database
include_once 'dbConnect.php';
include_once 'sanitizeString.php';

$activity = sanitizeString($_GET['activity']);

// query database on whether or not expertise is needed
$query = "SELECT displayExpertise FROM activities WHERE activity=$activity";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
$needExpertise = $row[0];

// Return the flags back to calling function

$arr = array('needExpertise' => $needExpertise);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

The alert(queryString); works find - so it's getting this far.  The alert('in .getJSON'); however isn't working.  I've tried commenting out all of the php function - so I'm wondering if I just cannot call $.getJSON from inside of an autocomplete select event?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what is wrong, what I would do is add handlers for the different statuses, particularly the `fail` case:

```
$.getJSON('php/checkActivityExpertise.php',queryString,function(data2)  {
    alert('in .getJSON');
    if (data2.needExpertise)  {
       activateBoxes();
    }
    else {
       deactivateBoxes();
    }
}).done(function() {
  alert( "done" );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  alert("Request Failed: " + err );
})
.always(function() {
  alert("always" );
}).complete(function() {
  alert("complete");
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did that.  It's giving me the error:  "Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"   Not sure why that error would be occurring?

Comment: what is your querystring?

Comment: The querystring is "activity=Aikido" (as an example - the activity depends on what the user enters in the textbox)

Comment: what happens if you go to site.com/php/getActivities.php?activity=Aikido in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON()` may be returning an error so it won't trigger the done handler - use this pattern instead from the docs

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
```

so you can put alerts in and see what the outcome of the call is